# Верстка под мобайл

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile

подскажите я делаю аналог мобильного приложения в виде сайта, и размеры элементов устанавливаю в 100% высоты экрана используя javascript, но когда открывается мобильная клавиатура, высота экрана становится в два раза меньше, и все плывет, подскажите как пофиксить данный баг. Желательно юзать онли html/css & javascript

Comment: ориентироваться на высоту экрана в процентах сам по себе плохая идея.

Comment: А как лучше сделать по вашему, если у меня задача не выходить за пределы высоты экрана?

Answer (score 1):

У вас где то листенер стоит на `resize` окна, у вас постоянно будет прыгать из-за этого на мобильной версии (при прокрутке вниз прячется верхняя строка браузера на мобайле как следствие будет пересчет..)

Сделайте к примеру при ресайзе окна - вызов функции с [matchMedia()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia) и только если сменилась ориентация экрана или ширина (не высота) - вызывайте пересчет высоты сайта

Comment: Подскажите как убрать resize?

Comment: вы написали что есть js, который считает высоту. В нем есть где то.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо